# Django Template doesn't work with a for loop in range. Why?

Tags: django, django-templates

VIEWS.PY

```
def index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    posts_quantity = range(1)
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'posts':posts, 'posts_quantity':posts_quantity})
```

HTML

```
{% for index in posts_quantity %}                        
    <a href = "{% url 'architectural_post' posts.index.slug %}" class = "post">
{% endfor %}
```

it gives me an error: `Reverse for 'architectural_post' with arguments '('',)' not found.`

But everything works well if I put 0 instead of index, like this (just for debugging):

```
{% for index in posts_quantity %}                        
    <a href = "{% url 'architectural_post' posts.0.slug %}" class = "post">
{% endfor %}
```

Why and how to fix it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Django is not interpreting `posts.index.slug` as `posts.0.slug`. Instead, Django is trying to find an attribute called `index` on the `posts` object.

It's not very intuitive, but that's how it is.

---

You can fix it by iterating over the `posts` directly:

```html
{% for post in posts %}
<a href="{% url 'architectural_post' post.slug %}" class="post">
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ok - I've got where the problem is. But unfortunately I need to have `{% for index in posts_quantity %}` for the further logic. It's a pity that is will not work that way. :( Thank you btw for the explanation.

Comment: @this_is_a_person If you want to know the index within the loop, you can use [`{{ forloop.counter0 }}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for) inside the loop.